# Ошибка исключения PHP

Tags: php

Имеется вот такой код:

```
    public function __construct(){ 
    throw new Exception('Исключение!');
    try{
    $a = 1;
    }
    catch(Exception $b{
        echo $b->getMessage();
    }
  }
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так ошибка бросается **вне** блока `try...catch(){}`.

```
public function __construct(){ 
  try{
    throw new Exception('Исключение!');
    $a = 1;
  }catch(Exception $b){
    echo $b->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Comment: Хорошо пристроился на счет скобки.

Comment: @alias, доволен?

Comment: @Other не стоит копировать чужое решение в свой ответ

Comment: @PashaPash Т.е. нельзя собрать все ответы в одном месте, просто для удобства? Никто же не говорит что я увидел отсутствие скобочки.

Comment: @Other ответы и так собраны на одной странице. Не вижу, чем копирование чужого ответа в свой добавляет удобства хоть кому-нибудь. Тем более в вопросе, вызванном опечаткой.

Comment: @PashaPash, очепяткой? Исключение выбрасывается вне зоны отлова. А вот мне было бы удобно прочитать все ответы/рекомендации/правки в одном сообщении. Дело вкуса, наверное.

Comment: @Other нет, это не дело вкуса. Дело вкуса - это скопировать сообщения в личный блог. А полностью скопировать чужой ответ в свой, тем более на сайте, где каждое сообщение оценивается отдельно - это плагиат.

Comment: @PashaPash Не полностью. Впрочем тема закрыта, конфликт мнений - мне было бы не жаль увидеть свой ответ в чужом сообщении, т. к. не факт что взято вообще у меня.

Answer (score 4):

Так же прошу обратить внимание на незакрытую скобку в этой строке:

`}catch(Exception $b{`

Думаю ваша ошибка из-за этого.